# What percentage of the 2013 budget does the sequester cuts represent?

Tags: united-states, budget

The sequester cuts to the growth in spending of the federal budget will result in a reduction in a increase in spending of [$85 billion](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/wp/2013/02/20/the-sequester-absolutely-everthing-you-could-possibly-need-to-know-in-one-faq/).

What percentage of the 2013 budget does this represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total budget: $3.803 trillion (requested)

$85 billion/$3.803 trillion = 0.0223507757  = 2.235%

sources:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_United_States_federal_budget
http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/budget/Overview